# Then, catch retornando un texto en html

Tags: javascript, promesas, try-catch

Estoy tratando de crear una promesa, y en el then, cath quiero retornar un texto para que se vea por pantalla como funcionaría? he tratado de crearlo yo pero no funciona o almenos no aparece en mi pantalla

```js
var promesas = new Promise((bien, incorrecto) => {
  setTimeout(() => bien("Operacion correcta"), 5000);
  setTimeout(() => incorrecto("Algo esta fallando"), 15000);
});
    promesas
      .then((correcto) => {
        let txt = document.getElementById("texto");
        return txt.innerHtml = correcto;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        let txt2 = document.getElementById("texto");
        txt2.innerHtml = error;
      });
```

```html
<div id="texto">Esto es un div</div><br />
```

Comment: Y cómo creas la promesa? De dónde sale? Estás seguro de que estás cumpliéndola o fallándola correctamente? Devuelve algo? Es imposible ayudarte sin ver de donde sale `promesas`! Debes proporcionarnos un [mre] para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: si añado console.log(correcto) si aparece mi mensaje

Comment: @Benito-B ya he añadido el resto de codigo restante

Comment: Te recomiendo checar la sintaxis bien, ya que el error de base puede generar el cierre de tu pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var promesas = new Promise((bien, incorrecto) => {
  setTimeout(() => bien("Operacion correcta"), 5000);
  setTimeout(() => incorrecto("Algo esta fallando"), 15000);
});
    promesas
      .then((correcto) => {
        let txt = document.getElementById("texto");
        txt.innerHTML = correcto; // El atributo correcto es innerHTML no innerHtml, las mayúsculas importan
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        let txt2 = document.getElementById("texto");
        txt2.innerHTML = error;
      });
```

```html
<div id="texto">Esto es un div</div><br />
```

Te dejo el código funcionando y en el comentario el error que tenías.

Por cierto, una promesa que se ha cumplido nunca va a fallar después, porque ya se ha resuelto correctamente si no me equivoco

Comment: Gracias!!! que fallo desconocia lo de las mayusculas! buscare algun modo de ver como funcionaria si falla gracias!!!